# Set appearance: none globally?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

globally?

If I apply this to `body{ }`, it doesn't seem to effect the document globally. Is there anything I can do to set these globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all element using the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) `*`, which matches elements of any type:

```
* {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: woah! Thanks =) Will accept this answer when it allows me